# Adding text annotations to a map

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, google-maps, dataframe

I'm using geoplotlib to siplay points on a map and i would like to add names to the points displayed in my map, like text annotations. But can't figure out how after googling it for a while and looking in the github documentation site. Here's the code to create the map:

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe containing the data to plot

locs = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a','b'],'lat': [-22.951916, -43.210487], 'lon': [-13.163141, -72.544962]})

# import eoplotlib.

import geoplotlib
%matplotlib inline

# Load the data

data = locs[['lat', 'lon']]

# Pass the data to geoplotlib.plot

geoplotlib.dot(data, color='b', point_size= 10)

# Display the map.

geoplotlib.inline()
```

This is the map generated:

[image]
How could i display the names of the column `names` in the df alongside the blue points in the map??

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [geoplotlib API reference for the geoplotlib.dot()](https://andrea-cuttone.github.io/geoplotlib/api.html#geoplotlib.dot) function provides an argument `f_tooltip` which accepts a *function* to generate a tooltip string for a point.

In your code, you do not need a separate `data` dataframe to plot the map and get the annotated tooltip. The `locs` dataframe already has the `name` column which will provide the string for the tooltip and can be used directly. Behind the scenes, the dataframe is converted into a dictionary of key-value pairs. In our case, we just need a simple `lambda` function to retrieve the `name` key from the dictionary for the corresponding `lat` and `lon`.

**Note**: I've used `geoplotlib.show()` as `inline` plots aren't working for me at this time.

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframe containing the data to plot    
locs = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a','b'],'lat': [-22.951916, -43.210487], 'lon': [-13.163141, -72.544962]})

#import geoplotlib.
import geoplotlib
# %matplotlib inline

#function to create a dot density map with annotated tooltip
geoplotlib.dot(locs, color='b', point_size= 10,f_tooltip=lambda r:r['name'])

# Display the map.
geoplotlib.show()
```

**The result**:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for you explanations and help!! it took me some time to figure out that the name of the point only appears in interactive plots when you pass the mouse over the points. This is not exactly what i was looking for, what i wanted to do is to display a static annotation above or below the point. But if there is no possibility of doing this, i think i will have to use this one.

Comment: What you are looking for is static labels for dots on the map. This seems like a good feature to work on, I'll follow the official [geoplotlib project on Github](https://github.com/andrea-cuttone/geoplotlib) and find out if any work is happening in this area. If I find something, I'll update the answer later. Or submit a PR if I can get a working solution for this feature. Currently, the API only provides the `f_tooltip` arg for the `geoplotlib.dot()` function which somewhat meets your requirement. A tooltip is the label information that appears when you mouse over an object.

Comment: Ok @amanb, thank you very much for your time and help, you kind of helped going a little out of the black with this. If you find something that closer meets what i need i'll be very grateful to you if you update the answer.

Since it's the first time for me using this package, i wasn't aware of what exactly a tooltip is, another thing i've learnt from you :) Thanks again!!